# Probblem with list from api json deserialized

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, json, deserialize

Im trying to get data from an api, I already deserialized the json,

But when I try to get the data in visualforce just shows me 1 value, and I dont get it, I ve been reading the documentation but still I have errors

Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong?

this is the response of my class

```
HTTPResponse response = h.send(request);
    Map<String,object> results = new Map<String,object>();
    List<Object> listResponse = new List<Object>(); 
    Map<String,object> MapeoNombre = new Map<String,object>();
    List<String> Nombre = new List<String>(); 
    Integer counter = 0;
    Integer num = 0;
    Integer i = 1;

        
    // Parse the JSON response
    if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        results = (Map<String,object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        Map<String, Object> body = (Map<String, Object>)results.get('body');
        listResponse = (List<Object>) body.get('asegurados');
        num = listResponse.size();
    System.debug('list:'+listResponse);
        } else {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            
        }
        
    for (Object asegurado:listResponse ){
                  if(counter<num){
                    MapeoNombre =(Map<String, Object>)asegurado;
                    Nombre.add((String)MapeoNombre.get('nombreAsegurado'));
                    i++;
                  }
             itemName =(string)MapeoNombre.get('nombreAsegurado');
             itemLastName =(string)MapeoNombre.get('apellidoPaterno');
             itemSecondLastName =(string)MapeoNombre.get('apellidoMaterno');
             itemRamo =(string)MapeoNombre.get('ramo');
             itemPoliza =(string)MapeoNombre.get('poliza');
            System.debug('nombre'+itemName);
            System.debug('apellida paterno'+itemLastName);
            System.debug('apellido materno'+itemSecondLastName);
            System.debug('poliza'+itemPoliza);  


            }
```

and this is my visualforce

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText value="{!ramopoliza}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:commandButton reRender="table1" value="Buscar" action="{!busqueda}"/>
        
        
    </apex:pageBlock>
   
    <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
    
    
  
    <div class="painel">
    <h1>MANCHA</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="1" class="celula_em_branco"></th>
            <th colspan="4" class="celula_azul_escuro">MANAGED SERVICES</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cor_cinza td_column">Nombre</td>
            <td class="cor_cinza td_column">Apellido Paterno</td>
            <td class="cor_cinza td_column">Apellido materno</td>
            <td class="cor_cinza td_column">Ramo</td>
            <td class="cor_cinza td_column">Poliza</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="celula_azul_escuro">{!itemName}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!itemLastName}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!itemSecondLastName}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!itemRamo}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!itemPoliza}</td>


        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td class="celula_azul_escuro">{!itemName}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!itemLastName}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!itemSecondLastName}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!itemRamo}</td>
        <td class="cor_azul">{!miprueba}</td>


        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Nombre}" var="f">
            <apex:column value="{!f}"><apex:facet name="header">Object Names</apex:facet></apex:column>
        </apex:pageblockTable>


</apex:form>
```

and this is the Json sample

```
"code": 1,
"message": "SUCCESS",
"date": "15/07/2022 23:57:00",
"body": {
    "asegurados": [
        {
            "ramo": "37",
            "poliza": "0000003101",
            "endosoQueModifica": "000000",
            "consecutivo": "00000001",
            "iniciovigencia": "01/04/2022",
            "finVigencia": "01/04/2023",
            "nombreAsegurado": "MARCO ANTONIO",
            "apellidoPaterno": "MARQUEZ",
            "apellidoMaterno": "SOTELO",
            "descripcionRamo": "SALUD INDIVIDUAL",
            "dependiente": "01 TITULAR",
            "fechaNacimiento": "14/08/1992",
            "numCertificado": "00000001",
            "numDeIncisoEnElCertificado": "00000001"
        },
        {
            "ramo": "37",
            "poliza": "0000003101",
            "endosoQueModifica": "100002",
            "consecutivo": "00000002",
            "iniciovigencia": "20/04/2022",
            "finVigencia": "01/04/2023",
            "nombreAsegurado": "SAYRA FABIOLA",
            "apellidoPaterno": "ORDUNO",
            "apellidoMaterno": "ELIZONDO",
            "descripcionRamo": "SALUD INDIVIDUAL",
            "dependiente": "D DEPENDIENTE",
            "fechaNacimiento": "22/10/1966",
            "numCertificado": "00000001",
            "numDeIncisoEnElCertificado": "00000002"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

asegurados is a list

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a look at the [apex:repeat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm) documentation that covers how you iterate over collections of data. As it is your controller provides just one value for each itemSomething value, instead of exposing an array of the asegurados for the Visualforce page to iterate using the `apex:repeat` element.

Comment: The code would also work better if you deserialize the data into Apex classes for the purpose, rather than as untyped data, since each of the asegurados's "properties" can be simply exposed in an Asegurado class as public properties and thus be easily used in the Visualforce page.

Comment: Ok, Im gonna try, Thank you